# How to create trigger before update execution?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables, tbl_PersonalInfoand tbl_User. I need to establish a trigger that is invoked before an update is made on the tbl_user table.

The trigger should check if the IdNum specified in the update statement already exists in the tbl_PersonalInfo table. If it exists, the update should continue execution, otherwise, the update should not continue execute

tbl_PersonalInfo:

```
  IdNum | FullName
  0001    John Regan
```

tbl_User:

```
UserId | IdNum | Username | Password
100     0001      admin      admin
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to make it more specific/clear (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this (untested)

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl_user
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.IdNum NOT IN (SELECT T.IdNum From tbl_PersonalInfo T ) THEN 
           CALL `inexistent function to trigger an error and abord`;
        END IF;
    END;
```

If you have MySQL 5.5 or above you can also raise an error that will be catchable by your application. to do so change the `CALL` with

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The IdNum doesnt exists in the PersonalInfo table';
```

Comment: thnk you so much..it works now...thanks a lot...it really a big help.... :)

Comment: hi thomas,,,can i ask u something if you're not busy..i am really new to this programming world.and i just want to ask for your opinion if you have any idea of an INFORMATION SYSTEM which is not transactional..it really helps for me in school..i just want your idea pls..(not a code) if you're willing to help me